# Deploying Rails 3 application to Tomcat using warble

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tomcat, jruby, tomcat7

I successfully created my war file using warble. I am trying to deploy my Rails 3 application in tomcat.

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and jRuby 1.6.7 supports it.

I am using windows and set an environment variable JRUBY_OPTS to --1.9.

If I go to the console (cmd) and type jruby -v this is the answer:jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.9.2-p312).....

After deployed, when I execute the application it fails due to a syntaxis problem. Analyzing the log file I can see the following:

System

jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_23) [Windows XP-x86-java]

Why is it using ruby 1.8.7? That is causing my error!
I tried to add SET RAILS_OPTS=--1.9.2 to my tomcat startup script but it has the same behaviour.

Note: If I start the server using jruby -S rails S it works well, it starts webrick using 1.9.2. But if I generate the WAR it executes using 1.8.7.

Any idea?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Comment: What tags? I think that I should write the main words in the title. What do you mean about tags?

Comment: You wrote "JRuby - " at the start. We already have a consistent, indexed, atomic tag system. Re-inventing it in ASCII embedded in titles with arbitrary styling is just noise. Usually I'd edit them all out, but even _I_ can't be assed with 64 questions' worth of it. Gees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run:

```
warble config
```

this creates a config file, `config/warble.rb`.  Open this file, and uncomment the following line:

```
# config.webxml.jruby.compat.version = "1.9"
```

and then repackage your war with warble.